# Laravel & Vue: Initialise Authentication from Store before rendering any components using

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am currently working on a project using laravel & Vue.

**What I want to achieve**
I want to authenticate a User before rendering any Vue Component to include the username in the Navbar.

**Problem**
I face the problem, that the Vue Navbar Component got rendered before the user has been authenticated and the status has been updated in the store. Hence, the navbar wont show the username, because the component not got updated.

**Question**
How can I access the store, commit a mutation (userauthentification) before I create the "New vue" with components? Or: How can I achieve reactivity that the component gots updated as soon as the authentication has taken place.

Alternatively I tried to use "computed" to update the state and update the username after the store.state.user has been updated. This does not work I guess due to the reactivity which I still not fully understand, although I've read a lot about it.

**Infos**
Here are some background infos:

- I use Laravel to set up routes (Frontend and Backend)
- I use a layout.blade file and include Vue components in the dedicated laravel view files
- Use JWT to authentify (this works fine)

Here is my layout.blade.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Gembox</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic|Material+Icons">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-material/dist/theme/default.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset(mix('/css/app.css'))}}">
    </head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">

        <header>
            <div>
                @include('includes.header')
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class=" main-container md-elevation-4 container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <footer class=" md-elevation-4 mb-1">
            @include('includes.footer')
        </footer>
        <script src="{{asset ('js/app.js')}}">
        </script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-material"></script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my header.blade.php

```html
<Navbar></Navbar>
```

Here is my store.js (user.js which is imported in store.js)

```js
import axios from "axios";
const state = {
  users: [],
  user: null,
  loggedin: false
};

const mutations = {
  CREATE_USER(state, payload) {
    axios
      .post("api/register", {
        name: payload.name,
        password: payload.password,
        email: payload.email
      })
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem("usertoken", response.data.token);
        state.user = response.data.user;
        state.loggedin = true;
      });
  },

  GET_USERS(state) {
    axios
      .get("api/user")
      .then((response) => (state.users = response.data))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "Problem bei der Liste der Nutzer");
      });
  },

  LOGIN_USER(state, payload) {
    axios
      .post("api/login", {
        email: payload.email,
        password: payload.password
      })
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem("usertoken", response.data.token);
        state.user = response.data.user;
        state.loggedin = true;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "Konnte keine Daten abrufen");
      });
  },

  AUTH_USER(state) {
    console.log(
      "Not authenticated with token",
      localStorage.getItem("usertoken")
    );
    axios
      .get("api/register", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}`
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        state.user = response.data.user;
        state.loggedin = true;
        console.log("New user has set", state.user);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "Konnte keine Daten abrufen");
      });
  },

  LOGOUT_USER(state) {
    localStorage.removeItem("usertoken");
    state.user = null;
    state.loggedin = false;
    console.log("logged out", state.user, state.loggedin, localStorage);
  }
};

const getters = {
  users: (state) => {
    return state.users;
  },

  user: (state) => {
    return state.user;
  }
};

const actions = {
  newUser: ({ commit }, payload) => {
    commit("CREATE_USER", payload);
  },

  listUsers: ({ commit }) => {
    commit("GET_USERS");
  },

  loginUser: ({ commit }, payload) => {
    commit("LOGIN_USER", payload);
  },

  authUser: ({ commit }) => {
    commit("AUTH_USER");
  },

  logoutUser: ({ commit }) => {
    commit("LOGOUT_USER");
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  mutations,
  getters,
  actions
};
```

Here is my app.js

```js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require("./bootstrap");

window.Vue = require("vue");

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import BootstrapVue from "bootstrap-vue";
import store from "../store/store";
import VueMaterial from "vue-material";
import "bootstrap-css-only/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "mdbvue/lib/css/mdb.min.css";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css";
import "vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css";
import "../sass/app.scss";

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(VueMaterial);

Vue.component("Signup", require("./components/User/Signup.vue"));
Vue.component("Home", require("./components/Home/Home.vue"));
Vue.component("Login", require("./components/User/Login.vue"));
Vue.component("Navbar", require("./components/Navbar/Navbar.vue"));

store.dispatch("authUser").then(() => {
  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    store
  });
});
```

Here is my Navbar Vue-Component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ user }}</p>
    <nav class=" navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark orange lighten-1">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent-555"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent-555"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent-555">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#"
              >Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a v-if="user.length > 0" class="nav-link" href="#">Logout</a>
            <a v-if="user.length < 1" class="nav-link" href="/register"
              >Register</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto nav-flex-icons">
          <li class="nav-item avatar">
            <a class="nav-link p-0" href="#">
              <img
                src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/avatar-5.jpg"
                class="rounded-circle z-depth-0"
                alt="avatar image"
                height="35"
              />
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  computed: {
    user() {
      return this.$store.getters.users;
      console.log(this.$store.getters.users);
    }
  },
  created() {
    console.log("Component mounted", this.$store.getters.users);
  }
};
</script>
```

I really appreciate your help!

Thanks
Jörg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are couple of issues i see in your code:

**Vuex Mutations are synchronous and Vuex actions are asynchronous**

[Ref: Vuex Documentation on actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html)

Your business logic must go in actions as they are asynchronous (i.e axios calls) and your data update/manipulation should go in mutations

In your "AUTH_USER" mutation you are making axios call which should be in your "authUser" action instead.

```
\\ Your SET_USER mutation could look like below 

SET_USER(state, payload) {

  \\ User data will be passed in 2nd param (i.e payload) 
  state.user = payload

  \\ if we get the data in payload then set loggedin 
  \\ variable to true otherwise false
  state.loggedin = (payload) ? true : false

}
```

```
\\ Your authUser vuex action could look like below, returning the promise 
authUser: ({ commit }) => {
   return axios
     .get("api/register", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}`
        }
      })
      .then((response) => {
        commit("SET_USER",response.data.user);                
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, "Konnte keine Daten abrufen");
      });

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! That saved a lot of trouble and work. Just to get it right: Whenever I have asynchronous Tasks I would put the promise into the ACTION and not MUTATION, correct?

Comment: Yes, basically all your business logic, api queries etc. goes in to "actions" then finally when you are done then you just "commit" the result by calling the appropriate mutation.

Here is the sample app i built recently, which might be helpful to you with component organisation, vuex, testing etc.

[git repo] https://github.com/techlab23/task-management-app